# How to record audio and play music on webpage on mobile phone with javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, audio, recorder

I have a web app that records sound and plays music from an embed youtube player (youtube player api). For the audio, I continuously record by starting the recorder after it ends in an infinite loop (speech recognition class). But I want to also play the youtube video at the same time. On a desktop, they both don't interfere with each other (or at least with a headphone and mic). But on my android phone, everytime it starts recording, it pauses the video and then resumes it when the recording ends. Is there a way to make the video not pause?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to break the stream into separate threads, and hope that you have enough power to handle them all.

I say "all" because while the your music stream may only be carried on one thread, the video from YouTube is still there.

In effect, you have to pretend to be the origininator and produce all of the a/v signals separately,  then allow the mobile device to consume them (assuming that the signals are properly encoded to begin with).

Comment: im not sure i follow.

Comment: Think of you computer like an audio mixing board. On a mixing board, each channel is assigned to a specific group of audio frequencies, and you can do things like eliminate the really low parts, and enhance everything else. Each channel is independent of the others, and with enough power, you can manipulate both the sound and the video.  In this case your computer is like the mixing board. When you have the headphones in, the computer knows to move the audio to a separate "channel" from the video, and the two can be run simultaneously.

Comment: On your device, the audio and video are running on the same "channel". But because they are encoded differently, they can't run at the same time, on the same channel, so the have to be separated before they are sent over the wire, and then put back together by the browser. You'd be better off making a movie with PowerPoint, to combine them into a single file.